# alwaysOn camera parameter Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, ros-melodic, camera, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering how I could use the `<alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>` tag in the `<plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">` Gazebo camera plugin.

Basically, I would like to set it to false, and switch the camera on or off whenever I need it, in order to save ressources essentially.

I read on another post ([here](https://answers.ros.org/question/193759/how-to-change-gazebo-plugin-parameter/)) that this parameter is not parameterized, because Gazebo cameras are not designed to be turned on or off, at least in 2014. Is it still the case?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356100/alwayson-camera-parameter-gazebo/) by [thibs-sigma](https://answers.ros.org/users/40527/thibs-sigma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I read on another post (here) that this parameter is not parameterized, because Gazebo cameras are not designed to be turned on or off, at least in 2014. Is it still the case?

I think that's a misunderstanding. Gazebo cameras can be turned on or off.

Looking through the code, I'm not sure if `alwaysOn` actually works on `gazebo_ros_pkgs` (where `gazebo_ros_camera` is), but you can pass the [always_on](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=sensor#sensor_always_on) SDF parameter directly to the camera sensor. Or you can always call `sensor->SetActive(false)` from a plugin.

> witch the camera on or off whenever I need it, in order to save ressources essentially.

You may want to look at [gazebo_ros_triggered_camera](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_triggered_camera.h), which takes pictures as you send messages on a topic.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2020-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1